# Active Directory - Using GPO To Update Multiple Versions Of .NET

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

OK, I have searched everywhere for this one.  I have all the MSI's and packages I need to deploy .Net 3.5 SP1, and 2.0 and 3.0 (which are prerequisites for 3.5).  I can't figure out how to install all of them at once via GPO.

Basically, the computers on the network do NOT have any version of .Net installed, and I need them to be at 3.5 SP1.  I know I can deploy each version via GPO, force reboot the client, then push the next one, force reboot, and so on.  Is there a way to streamline install all 3 at once via GPO?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to deploy the .NET Framework 3.5 via GPO.  Version 3.5 includes 3.0 and 2.0:

> MSDN: ["When you install the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, you get the 2.0
>   and 3.0 layers automatically."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)

Also, any updates to 3.5 will eventually install via Windows Update so no need to tack those on as additional installs.